# How to convert a Beam dataframe to a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-beam

Reading from [Beam dataframe overview](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/dataframes/overview/),
it looks like I can just convert a beam PCollection to a DataFrame using

```py
from apache_beam.dataframe.convert import to_dataframe 
df = to_dataframe(pcollections)
```

However, the `df` is still a Beam DataFrame not a pandas DataFrame. Is it possible to convert it to a pure pandas DataFrame?

(The dataframe in my problem is small enough to fit into the memory of single machine. Also, Beam DataFrame miss some critical feature so I still need the pure pandas functionality.)

Comment: There is a [jupyter notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/apache/beam/blob/master/examples/notebooks/tour-of-beam/dataframes.ipynb#scrollTo=8haEu6_9iTi7) provided by the Apache Foundation, showing the conversion between PCollections, Beam DataFrames and Pandas DataFrames and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use [Interactive Beam](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.runners.interactive.interactive_beam.html) in a notebook you can do this by calling [`ib.collect(df)`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.runners.interactive.interactive_beam.html#apache_beam.runners.interactive.interactive_beam.collect). This will execute the Beam job and retrieve the results as a *pandas* DataFrame.

I'd also love to know what critical features are missing in Beam DataFrames that you'd like to use, so we can prioritize them. We discuss some of the differences between Beam DataFrame and pandas [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/dataframes/differences-from-pandas/), but note that even the operations marked "wont implement" might get implemented at some point in the future, we'll just need to do some more substantial design work for them. Thanks for the question!

Comment: My need is to do `sort_values` for downstream program in python to operate based on the list of the values, or export to pure `.csv` file with sorted order for later analysis. Thanks for replying. Didn't know the interactive beam. Will give it a try.

Comment: Also, I need this to run on regular python script in production system without any  ipython or jupyter notebook. I was wondering if Interactive Beam still work?

Comment: Hm, in theory there's no reason that `ib.collect` needs to be used in a Jupyter notebook, but I think in practice interactive Beam was developed with a hard dependency on notebooks. So I suspect you'll run into issues if you try to use it in that way.

I filed a ticket to track improving this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-14515